# How to get app name for jss dictionary

Tags: jss, dictionary

How to get app name for jss dictionary, for request /sitecore/api/jss/dictionary///. Neither throws 404 error if not using sc_apikey or Unknown app name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSS app name is in the Sitecore config normally below the `\App_Config\Include\` in the Sitecore webroot.
You can found also found it with this url `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`
if you are admin, you can search on `<apps>` and found it below `<javaScriptServices patch:source="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config">`

See https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/app-configuration#app-configuration for the Sitecore JSS App configuration.

The url for the JSS dictionary looks like this:

```
/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/my-jss-app/en/?sc_apikey={05117388-CF7A-4984-B658-0B3E76886E62}
```

Fill in your app name and apikey and language.

Note: in the app config you can also set the dictionaryPath.